# Почему не срабатывает ajax запрос к файлу data.json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает ajax запрос к файлу data.json?  Где ошибка? По идее должен был добавиться еще 1 блок, но почему-то ни в консоль ни в html данные не выводятся. путь к файл прописан правильно.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({url: "js/data.json"}).done(function(data){
    var json = data,
      source = $('#blocks').html(),
      template = Handlebars.compile(source),
      html = template(json);    
      container.append(html);
console.log("SUCCESS:", typeof data, data);
  console.log(typeof data, data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log("ERROR:", textStatus, errorThrown);
  console.log(jqXHR);
});

});
```

```css
.blogItem{
 max-width: 380px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 margin-left: 8px;
 position: relative;
 h5{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: MontserratReg,sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 15px;
 }
 p{
  max-width: 380px;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: roboto-example;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
.comment_statistic{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  span{
   color: #999;
  i{
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
    color: $c_blue;
  }}
 }
 .blog_img{
  position: relative;
  img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
 .post_date{
  background-color: $c_blue;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: MontserratBold,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  span{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: roboto-exampleIt,sans-serif;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 5px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   color: #fff;
  }
 }
 }
}


.blog_header{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-image: url(../img/blogImg/bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: left 0;
 h3{
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
 }
 .main_link{
  color: black;
 }
 ul{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  } 
  li{
  display: inline-block;  
   }
   .active{
    color: $text_grey;
   }
   li:nth-child(2):before{
   content: '\2022';
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   }
}

.wrapper-articles{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header class="blog_header">
 <h3>Блог</h3>
 <ul>
  <li><a class="main_link" href="index.html">На главную</a></li>
  <li class="active">Блог</li>
 </ul>
</header>


<section class="articles">
 <div class="wrapper wrapper-articles">
  
  <a href="blog/article.html" class="blogItem">
   <div class="blog_img">
    <img src="http://kherson.life/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mobilki.jpg" alt="" class="blogImg">
    <div class="post_date">15<br><span>Jan</span></div>
   </div>
   <h5>Что популярнее: сайты или приложения</h5>
   <p>Нарастающая популярность мобильных устройств для серфинга в интернете изменила онлайн-ландшафт от начала и до конца. Если верить статистике, предложенной Smart Insights, 70% поиск...</p>
   <div class="comment_statistic">
    <span><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>542</span>
    <span><i class="fal fa-comment-dots"></i>17</span>
   </div>
  </a> 


 </div>
</section>


<script id="blocks" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each blocks}}
  <a href="{{post_link}}" class="blogItem">
   <div class="blog_img">
    <img src="{{src}}" alt="" class="blogImg">
    <div class="post_date"><br>{{date}}<span>{{month}}</span></div>
   </div>
   <h5>{{articleTitle}}</h5>
   <p>{{articleText}}</p>
   <div class="comment_statistic">
    {{#each statistic}}
    <span><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>{{views}}</span>
    <span><i class="fal fa-comment-dots"></i>{{comments}}</span>
   </div> 
  </a>
{{/each}}
</script>


 <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
 <script src="js/common.js"></script>
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\data.json

```
{
  "blocks":[
    {
    "post_link":"blog/article.html"
    },
    {
      "blogImg":[
        {
          "src":"img/blog/blog1.jpg"
        },
        {
          "date":"15",
          "month":"Jan"
        }
      ],
      "articleTitle": "Что популярнее: сайты или приложения",
      "articleText": "Нарастающая популярность мобильных устройств для серфинга в интернете изменила онлайн-ландшафт от начала и до конца. Если верить статистике, предложенной Smart Insights, 70% поиск...",
      "statisctic": [
        {
        "views":"542"
        },
        {
        "comments":"17"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: вместо ajax() - getJSON()

Comment: так ? $.getJSON

Comment: `$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "js/data.json"
}).done(function(data){
  console.log("SUCCESS:", typeof data, data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log("ERROR:", "[", textStatus, "]", "[", errorThrown, "]");
  console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87290/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----ajax----data-json).